# ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree?

Tags: angular, npm

When you try to create an angular project via the angular cli, you get this error

```
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: animation@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.7.1" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

please help me, I don't understand what needs to be done here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update (Angular 12.0.0)

Just a few hours after my answer, Angular 12 was released - which works perfectly with NPM `7.13.0`.

## Original answer (Angular 11.2.11)

Which NPM version are you using?

I just faced the same problem using version `7.10.0`. After downgrading to `6.14.13`, `ng new` worked as expected.

```sh
npm i -g npm@6.14.13
```

Currently, this seems to be the best solution if you want to create an Angular project. However, the respective [Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20719) has already been closed. So I expect the next Angular release to also work with the latest NPM version.

I hope I could help you.

Comment: Facing the same problem. I created my Angular project with the following command:

`npx -p @angular/cli@11.2.11 ng new myapp-frontend`

Answer (score 1):

Although downgrading to an older version of npm works, I would not recommend that because they updated it for a reason.

The new version can have included critical patches to security holes, or they can have included new or enhanced features.

So, here is my solution:
Notice what angular says:

```
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.7.1" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.6.0
```

So, you need to open your `package.json` file and change `jasmine-core` version from `3.6.0` to `3.7.1` which is the version that angular angular found in `karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.6.0`.

Then delete the `package-lock.json` file and run `npm install`.